# Impossible to generate metamodel in spagoBI studio with hive(CDH5|CDH4)

Tags: sql, hadoop, jdbc, hive, cloudera-cdh

While creating a JDBC connection between spagoBI studio and hive(CDH5/CDH4),This is my log :-

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

This is a continuation of log file /home/cloudera/SpagoBIStudio_4.2.0_linux64/workspace/.metadata/.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2014-06-30 01:38:31.422


Error
Mon Jun 30 02:51:46 PDT 2014
Impossible to generate metamodel

java.lang.RuntimeException: Impossible to initialize the model
at it.eng.spagobi.meta.editor.multi.wizards.SpagoBIModelEditorWizard.createModel(SpagoBIModelEditorWizard.java:241)
at it.eng.spagobi.meta.editor.multi.wizards.SpagoBIModelEditorWizard.performFinish(SpagoBIModelEditorWizard.java:217)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:811)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:430)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3540)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3161)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at it.eng.spagobi.studio.core.views.actionProvider.ResourceNavigatorActionProvider$13.run(ResourceNavigatorActionProvider.java:411)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3540)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3161)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Impossible to initialize the physical model
at it.eng.spagobi.meta.editor.multi.wizards.SpagoBIModelEditorWizard.createPhysicalModel(SpagoBIModelEditorWizard.java:340)
at it.eng.spagobi.meta.editor.multi.wizards.SpagoBIModelEditorWizard.createModel(SpagoBIModelEditorWizard.java:237)
... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:421)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:507)
at it.eng.spagobi.meta.editor.multi.wizards.SpagoBIModelEditorWizard.createPhysicalModel(SpagoBIModelEditorWizard.java:295)
... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Impossible to initialize physical model
at it.eng.spagobi.meta.initializer.PhysicalModelInitializer.initialize(PhysicalModelInitializer.java:121)
at it.eng.spagobi.meta.editor.multi.wizards.SpagoBIModelEditorWizard$1.run(SpagoBIModelEditorWizard.java:321)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDatabaseMetaData.getIdentifierQuoteString(HiveDatabaseMetaData.java:342)
at it.eng.spagobi.meta.initializer.PhysicalModelInitializer.initialize(PhysicalModelInitializer.java:112)
... 2 more
```

some of the related questions [hive methos not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212021/hive-method-not-supported) ,["java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?146651-quot-java-sql-SQLException-Method-not-supported-quot-when-retrieving-data-from-hive-table) which says

**Your original error results from using Cloudera's Hive driver which does not implement many JDBC API methods that PDI needs to function properly. That's why we have our own version of the hive driver in the cdh4 folder (called hive-0.7.0-pentaho-1.0.2 or something like that). Simply put, there should be no JARs copied from your cluster to your PDI client, the cdh4 folder already contains the correct versions of all necessary JARs.**

but I didnt find any spagoBI hive driver for CDH5/CDH4.I am able to connect to hive but while accessing table getting above error in studio ,I am able to access the table on spagoBI server.any help,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Cloudera's **.jar** files in order to be able to connect to CDH. Have a look [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_jdbc.html) and put all of the **.jar** files in the `CLASSPATH`. If running SpagoBI put it in `/lib` folder of the SpagoBI (Tomcat) server.